# how to fix columns with '?' characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a table with lots of data incorrectly saved with '`?`' symbols instead of the correct ones.

Most (if not all) of them where due to encoding differences, so instead of saving `á,é,í,ó,ú and ñ` (and the uppercase versions of each) they all where stored like '`?`'

for instance, i have the left ones instead of the right ones:

```
Se?ora < Señora
Espa?na < España
Jos? < José
Del r?o < Del río
```

and so on...

Obviously, I couldn't know directly, if a `?` represents any of `á,é,í,ó,ú or ñ` , **BUT** i have another table, which has the correct values (with accented letters and ñ) for most fields in the columns i need.

My question is, how could I build a query (or a script in PHP), that will update columns in table A (the wrong one) so the values are replaced with the correct ones from B.

Note that each "pair" of columns (from A and B) are always the same lenght, so the only difference is that in A they have '?' symbols, and in B they have the correct letter. With that in mind, I imagine I could build some kind of query using likes, and making a `like` each time, replacing any of `á,é,í,ó,ú and ñ` with `_`s in the like command.

e.g.:

if correct column from B is `'de la peña'`, the `like` would be `'de la pe_a'` so it would match `'de la pe?a'` in A, and then i just need to replace the value in A with the one in B, effectively replacing `'de la pe?a'` with `'de la peña'`.

the problem is I have no idea of how to make such a query / script.

any ideas?

Note 1, I know a good idea would be to simply replace A with B entirely, BUT the problem is that B has much fewer records than A, so i would only be able to fix as many wrong records in A as they have a matching pair in B.

Note 2. I already know how to correctly save **new** data from now on (it was a charset problem), and new records are now saved correctly, but i need to fix the wrong **OLD** data that is already there...

Comment: are you sure the data was stored correctly to begin with, and it's not just a client display problem? if it was stored wrong to begin with, you've got a huge amount of repair work ahead of you. if it's a client problem, then just change client settings.

Comment: how many rows of data in your second table (the good data). And can you adjust your second table to contain the "bad string" ?

Comment: @Marc B, it is not a client problem, data is stored with '?' litteral characters. And as I mention, new stored data is saved (and shown) properly.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey, table A (with wrong data) has a total of 80,389 row, of which, only 2010 have incorrect data (fields with '?'). Table B (correct ones) has 15,547 rows, of which obviously not all will have a match in the wrong table. And what do you mean with "adjust second table to contain the bad string"?

Comment: @JuanMendes no, charset is latin1, and collation is latin1_swedish_ci (MySQL defaults) in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what I would do is this:

First, reate a new table that maps the correct values to the corresponding incorrect values.  It would look something like this (we'll call it Table C):

```
(ID,CorrectValue,IncorrectValue)
(1,peña,pe?a)
(2,Señora,Se?ora)
```

Use Table B with PHP and regex to generate your Table C.  Pull out the correct values from Table B, use regex to replace the relevant characters with `?`, and then insert these new pairs (correct value from Table B, alongside its now-incorrect value as a separate field) into Table C.

Here's an example of how you might prepare your inserts for Table C (assuming that you've connected to your database and selected the items from Table B that you want to look at into a $result variable; I'm assuming mysqli here):

```
$inserts = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $correctvalue = $row['CorrectValue'] //assumes your select statement has returned CorrectValue as your candidates for correct values
    if (preg_match("/[áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚñÑ]/i",$correctvalue)) {  //only process those items that actually have one of the target characters
        $insert = array();
        $insert['CorrectValue'] = $correctvalue;
        $insert['IncorrectValue'] = preg_replace("/[áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚñÑ]/i","?",$correctvalue);
        $inserts[]=$insert;
    }
}

//and then process your inserts into Table 3
```

Once you have your table C set up, it should be a fairly easy thing to go through and update those items from Table A where they match the incorrect value in Table C, with the correct value in Table C.  The SQL might look something like this:

```
UPDATE TableA SET TableA.WrongValue = TableC.CorrectValue WHERE TableA.WrongValue = TableC.WrongValue;
```

This of course does not account for those items that you have that are not in Table B, but if that list is small (you described Table B as containing *most* of them, so hopefully it is), then this might save you a lot of time.

Comment: looks good, but could you please elaborate on how to write the regex to populate table C?

Comment: Also, two caveats: First, I'm including both capital and lower-case to ensure that /i works properly.  Some references (http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml, for example) indicate that regex doesn't handle international characters reliably.